# Como criar um Script dentro de um programa no terminal?

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal

Estou querendo desenvolver um script para automatizar umas tarefas repetitivas que venho fazendo no terminal. No entanto. Eu só consigo criar Scripts para Comandos diretamente no terminal, não para comandos dentro do programa.

[image: Imagem do programa onde desejo colocar o Script]

Como posso fazer para criar um SH que atuará dentro desse programa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entendi sua pergunta, mas na minha opiniao sua abordagem esta errada.

Eu nao consigo ver a sua imagem e também voce nao citou a linguagem de programacao, porém isso ja foi uma duvida minha e deixarei registrada aqui uma resposta para quem possa interessar se a linguagem for C ou C++.

Nao se cria scripts em executaveis, se usam as chamadas de sistema para executar diretamente os comandos.

Para isso existem algumas alternativas, a mais simples é usar dentro do executavel uma chamada ao `system()`.

Um exemplo banal seria:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Experimente passar algum argumento para o executavel, exemplo:

```
./binario "ls -l"
```

Também existem outras chamadas que fazem isso com o uso de `popen()` e `pclose()`, dependem somente da `stdio.h`.